# python for loop clients and flowers

Tags: python

I have to code a program where it asks how many clients have visited and prints out a number of flowers the shop gave out.

1. I need to use for loop.
2. Only odd numbers get flowers (1, 3, 5, 7 etc).
3. If you are third you get 3 flowers, 5th you get 5 flowers etc.
4. I ask for input how many people have visited.

Here's my code so far (it's in Estonian but maybe it is something to build on)

```
klientide_arv = int(input("Sisestage klientide arv ")) #asks how many clients
lillede_summa = 1 #gives a value to flowers
for i in range (lillede_summa, klientide_arv, 1): #i dont know if this is correct or no
    if (klientide_arv % 2) != 0: #checks if number is odd
        lillede_summa = lillede_summa + 2 #if odd adds 2 to total flowers
print ("Lillede koguarv on " + str(lillede_summa)) #prints out total flowers
```

Comment: Sounds like a Hackerrang/Codechef problem...

Answer (score 0):

you are close, but you are doing extra work

```
sum = 0
for i in range (0, number_of_people, 2): #  skip the even people
    sum += i+1
print(i)
```

if you have 5 people you only look at the 1st, 3rd and 5th and have 1+3+5=9 flowers